# How can i use external libraries in my java application

Tags: java, ocr, libraries

I am trying to develop an `OCR application` in `Java` by using some external libraries `e.g Tesseract` but I don't know how to add the Tesseract libraries to my Java project so that I can work with the trained data in `my java project`.

I've already seen the `Tess4J` but I don't know how to provide a way to link it to my Java program and this is my main problem

Comment: Learn how to use a build system like grade or maven. Or simply download the required jar archives and add them to your classpath when compiling / running your code. There are zillions of tutorials that show you how how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to get started with Tess4J is to get your sources from [jar-download](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j/4.3.1/source-code). It uses maven to compile the project and include all the dependencies. From there you can just follow [this](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/) tutorial from the developer.

After that learning the API is a jungle. The best resource I can find is the [documentation](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-4.3/), and forums here and there.